# I need to do the best 3 out of 5 but I can't get the code to return a score, what should I do?

Tags: python-2.7, counter

To elaborate on what I'm asking, I need to make a counter that allows me to decide the winner of the two opponents (basically a rock paper scissors game) by 3/5 matches. I have the code set to return the winners score +1 but its coming out as 0/0 no matter who wins and I don't know how to fix what ever problem I'm having.

```
#  Pkemon python 2.7.11    

import random
# pokemon list / attack
pokemon = ["pikachu", "Squirtle", "Arbok", "Butterfree", "Ekans", "Spearow","Xerneas","Zygarde","Timburr","Kangaskhan","Buizel","Abomasnow","Bergmite","Braviary","Burmy","Chandelure","Cofagrigus","Crawdaunt","Conkeldurr","Crustle","Cryogonal","Darkrai","Dewgong","Dragonite","Dunsparce","Dwebble","Empoleon","Foongus","Gardevoir"]    

# important things
def select_random(pokemon):
    pokepick = random.choice(pokemon)
    return pokepick
#the attacks
Attack = ["Air", "Water", "Grass"]
# Score/attack
def poke_score():
    score = random.choice(Attack)
    return score    

# things
user_poke = select_random(pokemon)
enemy_poke = select_random(pokemon)
enemy_score = poke_score()    

#staging
print "5 matches Best 3 out of 5"
print user_poke,"Vs.",enemy_poke
print "Select Attack"    

# user select attack
def make_score():
    score = raw_input("Air Water or Grass")
    return score
user_score = make_score()    

# outputs and battle sequence
def battle():
    etal = 0
    utal = 0
    print "current score", utal,"/",etal
    if user_score == "Air" and enemy_score == "Grass":
        etal = etal + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        return etal    

    elif user_score == "Grass" and enemy_score == "Water":
        etal = etal + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        return etal
    elif user_score == "Water" and enemy_score == "Air":
        etal = etal + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, enemy_poke, "Match Won!"
        return etal    

    elif user_score == enemy_score:
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, "Match was a Tie!!"
# forfeits match if no attack or incorrect attack is given
    elif user_score != "Air" "Water" "Grass":
        etal = etal + 1
        print user_poke, "Forfeits!", enemy_poke, "Wins!"
        return etal    

    else:
        utal = utal + 1
        print enemy_poke, "used", enemy_score, user_poke, "used", user_score, user_poke, "Match Won!"
        return utal    

battle()
```

Comment: In the "viewer" , how many white space the tab long ?

Comment: This question is unclear, please give a more detailed description of the problem in the question text.

Comment: 4 spaces and to elaborate on what I'm asking, i need to make a counter that allows me to decide the winner of the two opponents (basically a rock paper scissors game) by 3/5 matches i have the code set to return the winners score +1 but its coming out as 0/0 no matter who wins and i don't know how to fix what ever problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your code worked fine for me  after adding parenthesis for each print construct , and replacing  some statements ...

**[Demo](https://repl.it/Be7K/2)**   (**Updated)**

Comment: the demo threw back this error                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 30, in <module>
  File "python", line 28, in make_score
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined               i suspect the reason bing that the demo is in python 3 I'm coding in 2.7.11 and i tried what you said in my own editor and I'm still having the same problem of the code not keeping score.

Comment: @trey those errors you mentioned is because raw_input() has changed in python3 to input() , and the counter will never increase because the function will return it to zero each time you call it , so let the print before the return statement and after the "etal" and "utal" increase ,,,, see the Demo after Update –

Comment: ahh ok i see now, if its not obvious I'm new to python thx for the help